# How to identify the relevant elements within groups of XML

Tags: sql, xml

Is there a way in SQL to identify the instance of an XML element to return where the element is repeated and rules need to be applied to ID the correct parent?

E.g.

```
<group name="same" number="1" status="cancelled">
<element of interest>
</group>
<group name="same" number="2" status="cancelled">
<element of interest>
</group>
<group name="same" number="3" status="cancelled">
<element of interest>
</group>
<group name="same" number="4" status="completed">
<element of interest>
</group>
<group name="same" number="5" status="completed">
<element of interest>
</group>
<group name="same" number="6" status="completed">
<element of interest>
</group>
<group name="same" number="7" status="completed">
<element of interest>
</group>
```

I need the highest numbered, completed, instance of the “element of interest”

Comment: Is each `group` element in its own row, or is this one large xml document (e.g. in a single xml column)?

Comment: I didn’t think the presentation mattered, I can identify the group and element using SQL but I’m assuming (and this is what the results appear to suggest) it’s returning the first one it finds.

Comment: But, to answer the question, each group starts on a new row, as does each of the elements I’m interested in within the group